# A call to "new RegionInfo.Globalization.RegionInfo("pg");" fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the region info for Papua New Guinea but unfortunately, it is failing with the following call:

```
var region = new RegionInfo.Globalization.RegionInfo("pg");
```

An "ArgumentException" with the following message is thrown "Culture name 'pg' is not supported." "pg" is a valid two-letter country code for Papua New Guinea, so I was wondering if you guys had a similar issue before and how you went about getting the region info using an alternative method?

Comment: Found an alternate solution. Instead of trying to get the code from "RegionInfo.Globalization.RegionInfo", I am now getting a list of ISO standards country codes and then getting the correct code based from the associated country.

Answer (score 1):

Try uppercase:

var region = new RegionInfo.Globalization.RegionInfo("PG");

---

Try one of these names:

```
iso code:       PG, 598 and PNG
```

Obtained from [here](http://www.geonames.org/countries/PG/papua-new-guinea.html):

```
Papua New Guinea

country name:   Papua New Guinea 
iso code:       PG, 598 and PNG
fips code:      PP
capital:        Port Moresby
area:           462,840.0 km²
population:     6,064,515
currency:       Kina (PGK)
languages:      English (en-PG), Hiri Motu (ho), Motu (meu), Tok Pisin (tpi)
neighbours:     Indonesia
```

And don't forget to declare the culture name in ASP page.

Comment: No, uppercase code does not work. Same error message above.